# How to change the time before Live-view turns off on a 450D

Tags: canon-450d

When I am shooting in live-view, it is particularly frustrating how fast the display clicks of to conserve battery. Can I increase the time before it does this?

This question might be a little bit off topic, but I figured I would ask anyway.

Comment: This is something that is usually covered in the manual. Maybe have a look there to find the answer.

Comment: In 500D it's "auto power-off time" in the menus, by default 30 sec. It isn't specific to the live view, but it also controls the frustrating feature that you described.

Comment: @Gregmuellegger I looked pretty seriously through the manual and could not find it.

Comment: @Jukka you should add that as an answer, to earn the reputation from having the right answer :)

Comment: @Jukka still waiting for you to answer...

Comment: @Jukka LOL! If you insist! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jukka is correct, you can solve the problem by changing "auto power off" in the 450D settings menu (first yellow spanner icon).

The only thing I have to add is that even when auto power off is disabled, live view will still stop after 30 minutes to avoid overheating the sensor.

Comment: My 450D seem to turn off Live View at varying intervals. I am not certain why, however it seems to depend on the various exposure settings, primarily ISO. I am guessing it is adaptively trying to prevent any damage to to overheating...so its probably capped at 30 minutes, but primarily based on some kind of temperature sensor.